# Is it possible to implement a length(attribute) and sort by the latter with Spring Data Jpa Specification

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, criteria-api

I'm updating a Predicate, basically I want to convert the following query using the criteria API.

```
select t, length(name) lens
from train t
left join line l on l.id = t.lineId 
    where l.code = '14'
order by lens, name
```

Sample result:

| other columns | name | lens |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | AA-2 | 4 |
| ... | AA-3 | 4 |
| ... | AA-7 | 4 |
| ... | AA-9 | 4 |
| ... | AA-10 | 5 |
| ... | AA-17 | 5 |
| ... | BB-1 | 9 |
| ... | BB-3 | 9 |
| ... | BB-20 | 9 |

This is what I have done so fast:

1- In the service class

```
public Page<Train> getTrains(Pageable pageable, FilterRequest filterRequest) {
   if (filterRequest == null || CollectionUtils.isEmpty(filterRequest.getTrainsFilters())) {
        return trainRepository.findAll(pageable);
   }
   TrainSpecification trainSpecification = new TrainSpecification(filterRequest);
   // add a field lens in train => length(name) and add it to sortField in pageable
   // sortFields = [lens, name]
   Page<Train> trains = trainRepository.findAll(trainSpecification, pageable);
   return trains;
}
```

2- In the Specifcation class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TrainSpecification implements Specification<Train> {
    private transient FilterRequest filterRequest;
    private static final String CODE = "code";

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Train> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        Predicate[] predicatesLinesTrains = getTrainsLinesPredicates(root, criteriaBuilder);
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicatesLinesTrains);
    }

    private Predicate[] getTrainsLinesPredicates(Root<Train> root, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        // I think that update should be done on the root here but couldn't figure out how
        final Join<Train, Line> trainLineJoin = root.join("line", JoinType.LEFT);
        Predicate[] predicatesLine = new Predicate[0];
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.filterRequest.getTrainsFilters())) {
            predicatesLine = this.filterRequest.getTrainsFilters()
                .stream()
                .filter(filterCriteria -> filterCriteria.getValue() != null)
                .map(filterCriteria ->
                    {
                        switch (filterCriteria.getMatchMode().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)) {
                            case "IN":
                                return criteriaBuilder.in(root.get(filterCriteria.getName()))
                                    .value(filterCriteria.getValue());
                            case "EQUAL":
                                return criteriaBuilder.equal(trainLineJoin.get(CODE), filterCriteria.getValue());
                            default:
                                throw new OperationNotSupportedException(filterCriteria.getMatchMode());
                        }
                    }
                ).toArray(Predicate[]::new);
        }
        return predicatesLine;
    }
}
```

3- The FilterRequest class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FilterRequest {
    private List<FilterCriteria> activitiesFilters;
    private List<FilterCriteria> trainsFilters;
    private String sortField;
    private String sortOrder;

}
```

4- The FilterCriteria class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class FilterCriteria {
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    private Object value;

    private String matchMode;
}
```

According to SQL request, I have to create a field in train. This field should be updated when the database is queried. I can then add that field as a sortable parameter in pageable. I can't figure out how to do that for the moment.

Thoughts

1. I create a view (train_name_view) and use that with the criteria API
2. I create a field lens in train and use that to sort.
3. I look for more elegant way to update the Criteria API to get it done

Any idea on which approach is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the issue by using Criteria API.

I updated the `toPredicate` my Specification with the code

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Train> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    customSortByName(root, query, criteriaBuilder);
    Predicate[] predicatesLinesTrains = getTrainsLinesPredicates(root, criteriaBuilder);
    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicatesLinesTrains);
}
private void customSortByName(Root<Train> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        if (this.filterRequest.getSortOrder().equalsIgnoreCase(ASC)) {
            query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(criteriaBuilder.length(root.get(this.filterRequest.getSortField()))),
                criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(this.filterRequest.getSortField())));
        } else if (this.filterRequest.getSortOrder().equalsIgnoreCase(DESC)){
            query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(criteriaBuilder.length(root.get(this.filterRequest.getSortField()))),
                criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(this.filterRequest.getSortField())));
        }
}
```

The `customSortByName` correspond to the SQL query

```
SELECT name
FROM train 
order by length(name), name
```